# Can't pass ID and call Controller from ajax or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have a table of objects, and I want to pass their `ID` on click, and without refresh populate a div or table, I've tried with AJAX and angular but can not pass `ID`.

If I fix the `ID` on a specific number it works.

In the View:

```
<script>
    function CountryController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("/api/SportApi/GetCountry/").success(function (response) {
            $scope.controllerFunction = function (value) {
                console.log(value);
            }
            obj = JSON.parse(response);
            $scope.country = angular.fromJson(obj);
        });
    }
</script>
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" ng-href="#/api/SportApi/GetCountry/{{x.id}}" ng-click="CountryControler(x.id)">
    click for countries
</a>
```

Comment: can't you just append the ID to the url? Like `$http.get("/api/SportApi/GetCountry/"+someid)`.

Comment: Yes i did something like that, but how do i get the ID to the Function?

Comment: option 1 use routing ; option 2 use $index to get the index which you had clicked then get the id from the model array

Answer (score 0):

On your view, you should have:

```
<a class="item item-thumbnail-left" href ng-click="CountryControler(x.id)">click for countries</a>
```

where href will stop the link from reloading the page and the ng-click will call a method on your controller.
In your controller, you should define that function on the scope variable:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('ExamleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.CountryController = function(id) {
            $http.get("/api/SportApi/GetCountry/" + id).success(function (response) {
                $scope.controllerFunction = function (value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }
                obj = JSON.parse(response);
                $scope.country = angular.fromJson(obj);
            });
        }
}]);
```

Verify that you have bootstrapped angular js (by defining the root element of your html with [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp)).

Verify that you have attached the controller class to your view (by defining the controller html element with [ng-controller](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController)).

You should also verify that you are getting the right id on the view when calling "x.id".

$scope.controllerFunction seems unnecessary in this case.

Comment: I have a APIController  public string GetCountry(int id) that should recieve my ID and return JSON object from it.

Comment: Yes, the call is made on the angular js controller: $http.get("/api/SportApi/GetCountry/" + id)

Comment: <div ng-controller="CountryController"> indeed i have

Comment: what is the issue there?

Comment: Syntax Error: Token 'x.id' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}]. :/

Comment: You can't have <div ng-controller="CountryController"> because CountryController is a method in the ExamleController on this solution. so you should have <div ng-controller="ExamleController">

Comment: Are you properly initializing `x`? You can print the x within the `<div ng-controller="CountryController">` as `{{x}}`

Comment: I changed the div ng-controller and still nothing, and yes i tried with {{}} and without.. i tried everything :/

Comment: what do you get when you print {{x}}?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```
function CountryController($scope, $http, id) {
console.log(id)
            $http.get("/api/SportApi/GetCountry/").success(function (response) {
                $scope.controllerFunction = function (value) {
                    console.log(value);
                }
                obj = JSON.parse(response);
                $scope.country = angular.fromJson(obj);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Tried it, "Error: error:unpr Unknown Provider" Like the last time i tried. Unknown provider: idProvider <- id