# How to pass id to get data from api

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have api controller  `public string GetCountries(int id){}` and I also have ajax script

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('href');
            $("#xid").click(function () {
              $.ajax({

                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: "/api/Sports/GetCountries/" +  id,
                    success: function (data) {
                        obj = JSON.parse(data);
                        alert(data);

                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                $("#getCountry").append("<a href=" + obj[i].Id + ">" + obj[i].Name + "</>" + "<br/>");
                            }

                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

My view looks like this

```
<div style="float:left">
    <div ng-app="" ng-controller="biloKojiKontroler">
        <table class="tg">
            <tr ng-repeat="x in biloKojeIme">
                <th>
                <a href="#" id="xid" value="{{x.id}}">{{x.name}}</a>


               </th>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to click on anchor tag to get data from my api controller but when i click it redirect me to another page.

Comment: Check if there is javascript error after page load, what does this do `$(this).attr('href')` ?

Comment: you could ask your friend.,,, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235639/cant-pass-id-and-call-controller-from-ajax-or-angularjs

Comment: there is no error ... just redirecting to another page

Comment: i tryed that but then nothing happens

Comment: same...nothing works

Comment: Ps. an anchor tag by its design is meant to go somewhere when clicked. So trying to change its default behavior is a bad idea. you might want to try a different tag completely (one with an onclick event handler) and then style it to look like a link instead.

Comment: it executes script(redirect me to "#") but its not working...im not getting what i want

Comment: i used button also but when i click on it its like anchor tag

Comment: Try a div tag instead of a button, a button will submit a 'form' to it's action="" location and an anchor with a href will submit to that location. whereas a div doesn't have a default click location, but you can use an onclick on a div.

Comment: have a look at this too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506873/change-div-content-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Comment: yes.. when i use with data:"id"+=id throws me error but when i delete it then i get empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting the href for your link in the wrong place, it should be in the click handler.
You've set your `dataType` to `json` so the `data` parameter in your success callback will already be parsed.